# How can i prevent the logo from moving when i edit the text?

Tags: css

I'm building a menu with two sections and a logo between.

And i would like to know how can I prevent the logo from moving whenIi change the text from both sections. I would like to fix the logo, when i change the about us for exemple, i would like to see the about us editing and moving to the left side, not to the right side.

Sorry for my english:

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uL52rvwn/

HTML:

```
 <div class="menu">
    <div class="m-info">
       <ul>
          <li class="l-aboutus"><a>About us</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo"><img alt="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/bebZYcu.png" width="80" height="80" /></div>
    <div class="m-contact">
       <ul>
          <li class="l-ourcontacts"><a>Contacts</a></li>

       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did? I made the m-info float:left, and m-contact float:right, than made the #logo's margins negative to move it to the center.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uL52rvwn/3/

```
<style>
.m-info {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
.m-contact {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-right: -40px;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-right: -40px;
}

.menu ul {
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #eaeaea;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 11;
    position: relative;
}
.m-info ul li a, .m-contact ul li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.m-info ul li a:hover, .m-contact ul li a:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#c8c8c8;
}
.m-contact ul{
    margin-right:20px;
}
</style>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="m-info">
        <ul>
            <li class="l-aboutus"><a>About us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo"><img alt="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/bebZYcu.png" width="80" height="80" /></div>
    <div class="m-contact">
        <ul>
            <li class="l-ourcontacts"><a>Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning should work: http://jsfiddle.net/6L35a0up/7/

I changed the following CSS rule:

```
#logo img {
    left:50%;
    z-index: 12;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And moved the logo div to outside of the .menu wrapper.

Comment: This doesn't seem to "prevent the logo from moving" when the text changes. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6L35a0up/4/).

Comment: Updated answer. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The logo keeps it's position, but the text still overlaps the logo.

Comment: And the logo is not centered. Why was this accepted?

Comment: I wouldn't accept this answer, since the provided code does not push the text to the left and right, and keep the logo at its place when changing text length.